# Remove duplicates from list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code below, gets the answer through get request and writes the result to the list "RESULT"

```
for i in url:
    df = pd.read_html(i,header=0)[0]
    df = df.as_matrix().tolist()
    for item in df:           
        RESULT.append(item)
```

I use the code below to exclude duplicate entries:

```
def unique_items(RESULT):
found = set()
for item in RESULT:
    if item[0] not in found:
        yield item
        found.add(item[0])
NOT_DUBLICATE = (list(unique_items(RESULT)))
print(NOT_DUBLICATE)
```

It seems to me it is not optimal since it is necessary to get a list of all the rows to exclude duplicates.

How can I find duplicates before loading a rows into the list RESULT?

for example, the rows I write to the list RESULT:

```
[[55323602, 'system]
,[55323603, 'system]]
[[55323602, 'system]
,[55323603, 'system]]
```

Comment: @msanford I don't think that's a suitable dupe - the OP isn't really eliminating duplicates; they're comparing the elements by `item[0]`. We're gonna need a "eliminate duplicates based on a key function" sort of question

Comment: He is asking something which can avoid duplicates before appending to the list. check my answer!

Comment: @Aran-Fey Fair observation; I'll retract. Phillip you may wish to rephrase your title.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You say it's "necessary to get a list of all the rows to exclude duplicates", but that's not even true. Instead of building a list `RESULTS` and _then_ removing duplicates from that list, just skip the duplicates in the `for item in df:` loop.

Comment: @phillipwatts344, is it not possible to call `drop_duplicates` on your df before mapping it into a list? It would automatically drop all duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of use another method to exclude duplicate entries, append `item` to the list if `item` doesn't exist in the list `RESULT`. Then you don't need method `unique_items()`.

You can find duplicates before loading a row into the list RESULT using this:

```
for i in url:
    df = pd.read_html(i,header=0)[0]
    df = df.as_matrix().tolist()
    for item in df:  
        if item not in RESULT         
            RESULT.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a set instead of a list.

```
result = set()
for i in url:
    df = pd.read_html(i,header=0)[0]
    df_list = df.as_matrix().tolist()
    for item in df_list:          
       result.add(tuple(item))
```

Above code will exclude any duplicates. The only difference from your case will be that elements of `result` will be tuples instead of lists.

At the end, you can recast the set to a list by:

`result = list(result)`

Comment: 1) Your `result` is a dict, not a set. 2) `item` isn't defined in your loop. 3) `item` seems to be a list, and lists can't be stored in sets.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks for first two points, I corrected them. Regarding #3, you are wrong. A set can be updated with iterables: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update.

Comment: Yes, a set can be updated with an iterable, but that's not what we're trying to do here. We're trying to detect duplicate rows based on the first element, i.e. `item[0]`. Your code doesn't do that; it just tosses *all* the values in a row into a set. You end up with a list of values, not a list of rows.

Comment: If that is the case, the last edit should work fine.

Comment: That's definitely an improvement, but the OP's code compares the rows based on their first element (`item[0]`), and your code doesn't.

Comment: Given OP's example, the second element always seems to be 'system' so my code technically compares based on the first element. @phillipwatts344, correct me if I am wrong.